# Google picker GAPI.js does not work

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-js-client, google-picker

So the code was not changed and everything worked till today I noticed that my google picker does not work anymore. It opens the picker window and then freezes and gives this error message on the console -

`Uncaught TypeError: y is not a function
    at TE.r.T2 (2333244103-picker_modularized_opc.js:628)`

Below is my initialization of the google picker -

```
  const view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
  const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        .setAppId(this.appId)
        .setOAuthToken(this.oAuthToken)
        .addView(view)
        .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
        .setCallback(this.pickerCallback.bind(this))
        .build();
  picker.setVisible(true);
```

Anyone has experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just started receiving the same error about an hour ago. Same error 'Uncaught TypeError: y is not a function' that keeps running in the console. Will be watching this post but it seems to be an error on google's end.